# How to send a kill signal to stop a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If you start a Rails app with the `script/server` command, what command do you use to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` out the following file in your Rails tree:

```
tmp/pids/server.pid
```

and send any variety of kill command to that pid, or simply execute the following (assuming your tree looks like: `/my/rails/app`:

```
kill -9 $(cat /my/rails/app/tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

Comment: use kill-9 only as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have a pid file to kill if you are using a server like webrick, but you can get at it with:

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

which should show you all your Ruby processes, then kill the process running the server: `kill x`, where `x` is the process number.

Note that you will need to be running as the user running the Ruby command, otherwise `sudo` is in your future.

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep ruby
```

to see what servers are running and then:

```
kill -9 serverNumber
```

To kill the server.